# How can I automatically start another script when one script completes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I will create about 20 Google App scripts and I have to run them one by one. (When one of them completed, other one will run.)

So how can I do that?

Maybe can be done with triggers but I dont know how to setup like that.

*Edit:*
**I have a Google spreadsheet to hook data from a website. I'm gonna create about 20 Google Apps Scripts to hook data with IMPORTXML functions. You can ask me why you just dont create a single script? Thats because of 6 minutes script limit. So I want it to be clears cells and runs that scripts i created one by one. Also it should repeat this process every hour.**

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may want to restructure those functions so that they are easier to manage. See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).

Comment: I guess you gonna understand it right now.

Comment: Any answer to your question will depend on the structure of the source site and may also depend on the layout you require of the spreadsheet.

Comment: See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/13045193) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Create a master function that calls each function in turn, like this:

```js
function master() {
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
  myFunction3();
  myFunction4();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: And you can add tracking for each ie those that did not complete...

Comment: I've done like that before, but when it's like that many data became "N/A" or "Loading" because of too many IMPORTXML so that's not what I want.

Comment: The question does not specify spreadsheet functions like `importxml()` but Apps Script functions. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75022463/edit) your question and clarify what you have and what you would like to accomplish. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edited it can you check again?